# Open Word/Excel file using ASP.NET MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a `View` with a `button`, when a click that `button` I open a word file using `Microsoft Word`:

**JS**

```
//CLICK EVENT
$('.openDocument').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "openFile",
            method: "GET",
            async: false,
            success: function (respuesta) {

            }
        });

    });
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
 [HttpGet]
   public void openFile()
   {
      Process.Start(@"C:\Users\user01\Downloads\Test_document.docx");
   }
```

I have 2 questions about this:

1) When I publish the project locally, I can't open the file again (only when I run it), why when it is published it does not open? (Only the Microsoft Word icon appears in the Task Manager)

2) Already published, how can I do it so that another PC can open the file (to be shown on the other PC) and not open it on the server PC?

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this for question 1

```
public static Process CreateProcess(string exePath, string arguments = null, bool isHidden = true, string workingDirectory = null)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = exePath,
                Arguments = arguments,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory ?? Path.GetDirectoryName(exePath)
            };

            if (isHidden)
                processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

            return new Process()
            {
                StartInfo = processStartInfo,
                EnableRaisingEvents = true
            };
        }

        public static void RunProcess(string exePath, string arguments = null, bool isHidden = true, string workingDirectory = null)
        {
            Process process = CreateProcess(exePath, arguments, isHidden, workingDirectory);
            if (process.Start())
            {
                process.BeginOutputReadLine();
                process.BeginErrorReadLine();
                process.WaitForExit();
            }


        }
```